# KDE Remote Desktop Client

Tags: kde, rdp

I'm trying to connect to a Windows 7 professional box via KDE RDP. I'm able to connect, but RDP automatically logs off the Windows user when I sign on. Why can't I log in without disconnecting the current Windows user?

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't allow you to simultaneously use local and remote users on the same workstation. The only product they support to allow simultaneous remote users is Terminal Services, which runs on a windows server install. This behavior likely has something to do with money. ;)